# Kafka 1.0 & spring boot - Coordinator selected invalid assignment protocol: null

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka

We have the Kafka 1.0 client with the spring-kafka (version 1.1.1.RELEASE) because our spring framework is the 4.3.3.RELEASE but excluding the kafka 0.10.0.1 from this.
The broker is a 3nodes cluster with the kafka 1.0 version and the topics compatibility enabled

Sometimes the log writes the next exception until the disk is full

Container exception

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Coordinator selected invalid
>   assignment protocol: null     at
>   org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.onJoinComplete(ConsumerCoordinator.java:217)
>   ~[kafka-clients-1.0.0.jar!/:?]    at
>   org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.joinGroupIfNeeded(AbstractCoordinator.java:367)
>   ~[kafka-clients-1.0.0.jar!/:?]    at
>   org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureActiveGroup(AbstractCoordinator.java:316)
>   ~[kafka-clients-1.0.0.jar!/:?]    at
>   org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.poll(ConsumerCoordinator.java:295)
>   ~[kafka-clients-1.0.0.jar!/:?]    at
>   org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollOnce(KafkaConsumer.java:1138)
>   ~[kafka-clients-1.0.0.jar!/:?]    at
>   org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll(KafkaConsumer.java:1103)
>   ~[kafka-clients-1.0.0.jar!/:?]    at
>   org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer$ListenerConsumer.run(KafkaMessageListenerContainer.java:532)
>   [spring-kafka-1.1.1.RELEASE.jar!/:?]  at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>   [?:1.8.0_161]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [?:1.8.0_161]
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_161]

Do you know why is this log printing? what are the causes of this error? Or how to prevent this?

The partition assignment is the default, Range. This does not occur from the start of the service. Is after hours or days of service

We think that a application node that is a consumer does a fullgc, this is detected and tries to change to another application node but it can't and begins to write this... but we don't know if is cause or consequence.

Thanks!!

Comment: what is your assignment strategy on the partitions? Range, Round robin or anything custom?

Comment: Check the code here https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/1.0/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/internals/ConsumerCoordinator.java

Comment: Basically from the code , it seems your partition assignment strategy name used is invalid.

Comment: The partition assignment is the default, Range. This does not occur from the start of the service. Is after hours or days of service